# How make a layout available to a dialog

Tags: android

In my activity there are 3 buttons. By clicking on the first button, I want a dialog to appear with a graph (in the layout itself it works fine).

```
 btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 dialog = new Dialog(ChartsDuration.this);
                 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_charts1);     

// code to show a graph. Here I have a function that calls  drawChartAll(), 
// but since the layout is declared outside the dialog it cannot render it to the
// linearlayout, and my graph1 linearlayout will be empty.

                 dialog.show();


            }
        });
```

Tha graph uses data that are queried in functions outside like

```
public void drawChartAll()
   {
//blablabla and this is how I define the layout and render the graph to it:
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);   
mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(ChartsDuration.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values),renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
mChartView.setBackgroundColor(renderer.getBackgroundColor());
layout.addView(mChartView);
}
```

So without the dialog, I can easily show the graph in the graph1 LinearLayout e.g below the buttons, because they are "on the same levels", but I want to show the graph in a dialog opened by clicking on a button. Because if I were in a dialog I would do this: `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.graph1);`   But now I cannot do this, since I am outside the dialog.

How do I reach this layout?

**Edit**:

user113215 I did this:

in the activity:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ChartsDuration.this);
 customDialog = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_charts1, null);


        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 dialog.setContentView(customDialog);
                 //queries

                 dialog.show();


            }
        });
```

and in drawChartAll:

```
   public void drawChartAll()
       {
    //code
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    }
```

Is this what you mean? This throws me a nullpointer exception to `dialog.setContentView(customDialog);` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `dialog`variable a field in your Activity class. You can reach it from anywhere. You can still use `dialog.findviewbyid` throughout you Activity. Just make sure `setcontentView` has been called before you call `findviewbyid`

Edit: I hope when you wrote **`since I am outside the dialog.`** you meant you could not access the variable

Comment: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1); is declared in a function in the activity. When the dialog calls that function, the graph is not loaded since it is looking for sg like this: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.graph1);

Comment: change the function drawChartAll , use dialog.findviewbyid everywhere

Comment: That was the key. To define the dialog outside the btn onclicklistener and use dialog.findviewbyid everywhere. Never would have thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're having trouble manipulating things on the layout that's going into the dialog. Instead of calling `setContentView(int)`, inflate the layout yourself and then use `setContentView(View)`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
ViewGroup customDialog = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_charts1, null);

// Do chart things here
// Prefix all calls to findViewById with "customDialog."
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.graph1);
mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(ChartsDuration.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values),renderer,Type.DEFAULT); 
mChartView.setBackgroundColor(renderer.getBackgroundColor()); 
layout.addView(mChartView);

// Put the manipulated layout into the dialog
dialog.setContentView(customDialog);
```

You can use this same trick to take advantage of the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) class while still filling the dialog with a custom layout.